# How to get the node from a node-set matching an attribute value?

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have a node-set stored in a variable like below

```
<xsl:variable name="myXML">
<list>
<input name="First" elementName="FirstName" option="one" />
<input name="Second" elementName="SecondName" option="Two" />
<input name="Third" elementName="ThirdName" option="Three" />
<input name="Fourth" elementName="FourthName" option="Four" />
</list>
</xsl:variable>
```

My code below retrieves the node and its attributes correctly.
But the for-each in the below code repeats even after finding the match, until it reaches the last `<input>` node.
So if i have a big list with many `<input>` nodes in my node-set, it may cause performance issue.
I need to re-factor the below code much simpler, may be without for-each.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:variable name="checkName" select="'Third'" />
<xsl:variable name="getNode">
<xsl:for-each select="$myXML/list/input">
    <xsl:if test="./@name=$checkName">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="element" select="$getNode/input/@elementName" />
<xsl:variable name="option" select="$getNode/input/@option" />
<element><xsl:value-of select="$element" /></element>
<option><xsl:value-of select="$option" /></option>
</xsl:template>
```

All i wanted is, i have a input variable checkName="Third" and i need the value of the attributes 'elementName' and 'option' in two different variables that matches the value in the name attribute of the `<input>` node. Please help me with a solution and also i don't want to use exslt or any other extensions.

Comment: Which XSLT 1.0 processor do you use? In my understanding of XSLT 1.0 the variable named `myXML` is of type result tree fragment and doing `for-each select="$myXML/list/input"` should give an error with an XSLT 1.0 processor.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for an easy solution which is much shorter and much more efficient than your current code. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use a [predicate](http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/construct_predicate.html) filter to compare the `@name` to the `checkName` variable.

The stylesheet can be greatly simplified by removing the `for-each` and extra variables to use simple XPATH statements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:variable name="myXML">
        <list>
            <input name="First" elementName="FirstName" option="one" />
            <input name="Second" elementName="SecondName" option="Two" />
            <input name="Third" elementName="ThirdName" option="Three" />
            <input name="Fourth" elementName="FourthName" option="Four" />
        </list>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="checkName" select="'Third'" />
        <element><xsl:value-of select="$myXML/list/input[@name=$checkName]/@elementName" /></element>
        <option><xsl:value-of select="$myXML/list/input[@name=$checkName]/@option" /></option>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is not an XSLT 1.0 solution. You can't use `/` operator with RTF.

Comment: @Alejandro - Yes, you are correct. It happened to work for me in oXygen with Saxon 9.2, but using the variable as an RTF isn't standard 1.0. @dhinu had been using it, so I'm assuming it works for him/her.

Answer (score 1):

> My code below retrieves the node and
>   its attributes correctly. But the
>   for-each in the below code repeats
>   even after finding the match, until it
>   reaches the last  node. So if i
>   have a big list with many 
>   nodes in my node-set, it may cause
>   performance issue. I need to re-factor
>   the below code much simpler, may be
>   without for-each.
>
> ```
> <xsl:variable name="getNode">
>  <xsl:for-each select="$myXML/list/input">
>      <xsl:if test="./@name=$checkName">
>        <xsl:copy-of select="." />     
>      </xsl:if> 
>  </xsl:for-each> 
> </xsl:variable>
> ```

**Use**:

```
<xsl:variable name="getNode" select="$myXml/list/input[@name=$checkName]"/>
```